# Parse Issue Expected identifier

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gamekit, void

I am making an iPhone application and have had the error "Expected Identifier". In the error log there is a bold "parse issue" above it. It is in this code:

```
-(void) showLeaderboard:{
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];

if (leaderboardController != nil)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];  }}
-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

The actual error is on the line:"-(void) showLeaderboard:{" And the little pointer is on the little bracket. Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `:` from the method. It should only say `-(void) showLeaderboard {`